# Collate SQL Query in OBDC Connection query

Tags: excel, sql-server-2012, odbc

I'm using this line:

```
on x.RiskIdentifier COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT = f.UnderlyingIdentifier COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
```

As a part of sql server 2012 query which is perfectly working

Now, I'm trying to use it in Excel with an ODBC connection. This is no longer working. I think Collate does not work in excel.

Is there any solution ?

Thanks

Comment: Make your query a stored procedure or view first, then query from there. That way, SQL Server is the only thing that has to know about your collations.

Comment: What do you mean by stored procedure or view first ?

Thanks

Comment: For any given single SQL Server `SELECT` statement (caveat - some technical restrictions may apply), you can create a view by using `CREATE VIEW <ViewName> AS <SQL Statement>`. If your SQL has more than one SQL command, then you can use `CREATE PROCEDURE <ProcName> [@Param1 <datatype> [, @Param2 <datatype>...] AS BEGIN <Your SQL Commands Here> END`. Either of these things can be used as the source for loading your Excel spreadsheet.